# SSRS filter to show more than one type of entry

Tags: reporting-services

I'm sure this is pretty simple, I need an expression that I an use within Group Properties to show only a certain type of product. My Column title is Product_Group within this are fruit and veg.  Potatoes, Carrots, peas, Oranges and Apples.  I want my filter to work so that when I run my report only apples and oranges appear.  I thought this would be as simple as

```
=(Fields!Product_Group.Value ="apples")and(Fields!Product_Group.Value = "oranges")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your AND needs to be an OR

```
=(Fields!Product_Group.Value ="apples")OR(Fields!Product_Group.Value = "oranges")
```